# How do I convert a TIF to PNG in Java?

Tags: java, image, png, tiff, image-conversion

Under Java what is the best way to go about converting an TIF file to a PNG?

Simplicity is preferable, but if the simplest way is to use a third party library then I would consider that solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, install [JAI](https://jai.dev.java.net/). Then install [JAI/ImageIO](https://jai-imageio.dev.java.net/). Then do

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final BufferedImage tif = ImageIO.read(new File("test.tif"));
    ImageIO.write(tif, "png", new File("test.png"));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on with the non-standard install? Usually Java libraries are just JAR files that you place inside your CLASSPATH, but JAI installs native DLLs as well. How does this work if you deploy to a webserver?

Comment: You can also get pure-java JAI, but there's no reason to do so, if your platform is supported by the native code.

If you deploy your app to a web server, then the server's JRE must also have the JAI and JAI/ImageIO extensions installed as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg, Do you need to include the JARs on the classpath or does installing the extensions make it part of the JRE?

Comment: The installers do everything required to make it "just work" with your JRE.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg, I am having no luck with this approach; the ImageIO.read() call is returning null. Any suggestions?

Comment: I should also note that I am using the approach laid out at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.imageio/DetermineFormat.html to check to see if TIF files are supported for read operations, according to canReadFormat(), they are not.

Comment: Right. First you have to install JAI and JAI/ImageIO.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg, yeah I installed both of those, I've ever tried copying the DLLs manually into various JDK and JREs I have installed on my system. I am having no luck.

Comment: Once I include the JAI and JAI ImageIO JARs in my path it seems to be working. I think this may bypass the DLLs and make native Java calls, which may be less preformant.

Comment: This site has some good tips to see if JAI is installed properly programmatically http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=64311.

Comment: Full and simple answer!! After searching and trying out 5-6 different codes for the last 10 hours, this simple little code solved my problem. <3

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys, but where are the download links for JAI and JAI/ImageIO??

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg what about multi tiff

Answer (score 7):

Use [imageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) java libraries like [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/), their performance and quality is much better then JAI

for example:

```
import org.im4java.core.ConvertCmd;
import org.im4java.core.IMOperation;

public static void convertTifToPng(File inputImage, File outputImage){
  IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
  op.addImage(); //place holder for input file
  op.addImage(); //place holder for output file

  ConvertCmd convert = new ConvertCmd();
  convert.run(op, new Object[]{inputImage.getAbsolutePath(), outputImage.getAbsolutePath()});
}
```

maven dependency for im4java is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>im4java</groupId>
  <artifactId>im4java</artifactId>
  <version>0.98.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I agree that IM's quality is excellent, but I would be very nervous about using it in-process like that (because, in my opinion, the engineering quality is not good, and there can be fatal crashes). I'd instead shell-out to `convert` using ProcessBuilder, if I were going to use IM.

Comment: @giladbu: ImageMagick is great and I do it the way Jonathan is suggesting but I just want to comment on the "quality" part: I very much doubt that JAI would produce an image of worse quality than ImageMagick when *reading* a lossy TIFF (should the TIFF of the OP be lossy). As for PNG, it's lossless and JAI cannot go wrong there. So in the TIFF-to-PNG case I don't agree that ImageMagick's quality would be better than JAI. For TIFF-to-JPG now we'd be talking about something entirely different and I'd use ImageMagick without thinking twice about it.

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize that PNGs were lossless.

Comment: So what does the ImageMagic approach require? An installation of the ImageMagic command line tools and then plugging the im4java jars into my project?

Comment: im4java does shell-out to convert using ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Java advanced imaging APi is a good library for image manipulations

http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/iio.html

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that, I honestly have no idea how to install it. They have a download ZIP that contains a JAR file with an EXE file inside of it. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

Download JIMI Software Development Kit jimi1_0.zip and set JimiProClasses.zip to your classpath

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7259-jimi_sdk-1.0-oth-JPR

JIMI is older java image library, but it is easy to use and there is no platform dependent code (no native executables, can use it like standard jar)

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import com.sun.jimi.core.Jimi;

public class JIMIImageConverter {

public static byte[] convert(byte[] inBytes, String inMimeType, String outMimeType) throws Exception{

    Image rawImage = Jimi.getImage(new ByteArrayInputStream(inBytes), inMimeType);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Jimi.putImage(outMimeType, rawImage, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toByteArray();

}

}
```

where inMimeType and outMimeType are graphics formats mimetypes

Comment: it works fine for jpg, jpeg, png but it doesn't work for tiff

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this code, works for me

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;

public class ImageConvert {

    public static RenderedImage[] readMultiPageTiff(String fileName)throws IOException{
           File file = new File(fileName);
           SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(file);
           ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", seekableStream, null);
           int numPages = decoder.getNumPages();
           RenderedImage image[]= new RenderedImage[numPages];
           int count = 0;
           for(int i=0;i<decoder.getNumPages();i++){
               image[i] = decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
               count++;
           }

           String newFolderName;
           String s3 = fileName;
           String [] temp = null;
           temp = s3.split("\\.");


           int j;
               j = 0;
               do{
                     newFolderName = temp[j];
                     String spoonFeeding = newFolderName;
                     File f = new File(spoonFeeding);
                     f.mkdirs();
                     j++;
               }while (j<1);

           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               RenderedImage page = decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(i);
               File fileObj = new File(newFolderName+"/" + (i+1) + ".png");
               System.out.println("Saving " + fileObj.getCanonicalPath());
               ParameterBlock parBlock = new ParameterBlock();
               parBlock.addSource(page);
               parBlock.add(fileObj.toString());
               parBlock.add("png");
               RenderedOp renderedOp = JAI.create("filestore",parBlock);
               renderedOp.dispose();
           }
           return image;
        }

}
```