# How to programmatically convert tif images to jpeg in Adobe CQ5.5

Tags: aem

I have written a servlet to be deployed in Adobe CQ5.5 that uploads images from a hard drive and creates assets for the images in the CQ repository. The images are all high resolution images (tif) and we would like to be able to also create a jpeg image from the tif. The low res image would be associated with an asset page and the high-res would be available for download.

My question is: Is there a way to programmatically convert the images from within CQ? I've searched for solutions to this but have not found any that solve our problem.

Comment: Hm, one quick search here at SO brought up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429011/how-to-convert-tiff-to-jpeg-png-in-java
You just need to deploy the required jar with your bundle.

Comment: Yeah - I had found that as well and it works fine until I try to deploy it into CQ's OSGI environment. Apparently the JAI API being used depends on com.sun.image.codec.jpeg and the OSGI container won't resolve the dependency.

Comment: Try to add "com.sun.image.*" to the sling.properties for the property: org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation

Comment: I gave that a try but it still won't resolve the dependency. After deploying my bundle I see the following error when I display the bundle info in system/console/bundles: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg -- Cannot be resolved and overwritten by Boot Delegation