# Can I make Android WebView support other image formats (e.g. TIFF)?

Tags: android, image, android-webview, tiff

For example, how to make the following HTML page actually display the image, in an Android WebView?

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://www.alternatiff.com/sample.tif">
</body>
</html>
```

Any (hacking) suggestion is appreciated. I am only an app developer and cannot control the whole system, so modifying the OS source code is not applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but this is what I would do:

- Make a subclass of `WebViewClient`
- Override `shouldInterceptRequest()` to check the URL and see if a TIFF was requested.  If it was not a TIFF, return `null` to tell the `WebView` to handle the request itself.
- If a TIFF was requested, open `HttpURLConnection` to the TIFF url and read the data, convert the TIFF to a JPEG or PNG [ex. How to convert TIFF to JPEG/PNG in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429011/how-to-convert-tiff-to-jpeg-png-in-java) and set up an `InputStream` to read the JPEG/PNG image bytes.
- Return a `WebResourceResponse` with the mime type (i.e. image/jpeg) and the `InputStream` you created to read the image data.
- Call `setWebViewClient` on the webview with an instance of your `WebViewClient` subclass.

Rather than converting on the device using a JNI library, I think I would convert the image on a server and open the HttpURLConnection to the pre-converted image stream, i.e.  http://example.com/convert_tiff?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alternatiff.com%2Fsample.tif&fmt=JPEG and then return that `InputStream` in the `WebResourceResponse`.  I guess it depends on how cheap the bandwidth and server resources are for you.

Comment: Looks like your best bet for decoding TIFF is using JNI, here's a project you can look at: https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/

Comment: It seems very likely to be the right way! Thank you. I will try this and let you know how it works.