# Android WebViewClient's shouldInterceptRequest method: is there any equivalent of that in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In Android, I can use WebViewClient's [shouldInterceptRequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) method to custom WebView's handling of certain URL. However, I cannot find anything equivalent in iOS's UIWebView and UIWebViewDelegate. Is there any way I can achieve the same purpose of shouldInterceptRequest in iOS, i.e., allow me to return data for a resource request?

What I want to do is to make the web view support some private image formats(see the question: [Can I make Android WebView support other image formats (e.g. TIFF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534120/can-i-make-android-webview-support-other-image-formats-e-g-tiff)).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NSURLProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html) is the right way.

See the following references:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial, http://objectivetoast.com/2014/05/19/intercepting-requests-with-nsurlprotocol/, and [more](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=728&q=nsurlprotocol+ios&oq=nsurl+protocol+ios&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i13j0i13i30l2j0i8i13i30j0i8i30j0i8i13i30j0i13i30.7543.7647.0.9333.2.2.0.0.0.0.238.238.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.1.237.PoxU8DoQWMo).

Answer (score 0):

There's not a method exactly like that in UIKit, but you can get the same effect by implementing `-[UIWebViewDelegate webView:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]`. In this method you can call `-[UIWebView loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:]` to load your own data and then return NO so the web view doesn't try to load it's own data.

Comment: The methods you mentioned are called for the whole page and not every resource (like <img src="">) in the page, which means I have to parse and reproduce the whole page before loading. Am I right?

Comment: It's called for sections of the page, I'm not sure for every image but I imagine it would be since each image requires a separate url request. Give it a try and let us know!

Comment: It's called for the whole page (or frame), but not for every resource.

Comment: Yeah `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` is the equivalent of Android's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, which is only called when the page URL changes, not `shouldInterceptRequest`, which is called for every resource retrieved from the browser. So this doesn't really answer the OP's question. @shengbinmeng's answer is correct.

Comment: Addendum: NSURLProtocol does not work consistently with WKWebView. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208229/wkwebview-and-nsurlprotocol-not-working