# How to detect resource request in an iOS webview, same as Android's "shouldInterceptRequest"?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, xmlhttprequest, wkwebview

In the iOS **WKWebView**, is there a way to detect when the website makes a **resource request** (e.g. an HttpRequest via Ajax)?

In *Android*, there is a very convenient method "*shouldInterceptRequest*", but I cannot find an equivalent in iOS.

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote button states *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Your question does not show any research effort. `WKWebView` has a couple of delegates with lots of methods. Have you tested to see if any of them are called for your use case? Have you done any searching? Updating your question with the results of these efforts would prove beneficial.

Comment: I did some research, but I couldn't find a way to detect a resource request. The question is very clear.

Comment: Did you try all of the possible delegates and their methods? What were the results? Please put those results in your question. Also mention when research you've done. This avoids duplication of effort by prospective answerers.

Comment: @HangarRash whatever I tried didn't work for me. I don't see any point in adding my failed attempts in the question. I also found this question, which doesn't seem very hopeful, even though it's quite old: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541931/android-webviewclients-shouldinterceptrequest-method-is-there-any-equivalent-o?rq=2

Comment: @DanieleB There is a way of intercepting WKWebview requests but only with custom scheme e.g. mycustomscheme://test.com using `setURLSchemeHandler` method on WKWebview and implementing `WKURLSchemeHandler`. When you try to use http, https as custom scheme app will crash because Apple does not allow doing it.

Comment: unfortunately using a custom scheme doesn't help when trying to monitor HTTP Ajax requests

Comment: Did you maybe tried inject JS script using `addUserScript` that will override XMLHTTPRequest (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28513219/11471446)? And inside of override send window.webkit.messageHandlers.{your_handler}.postMessage() (you need to register your_handler for webview).

Comment: That looks like a very hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As we know we can NOT `WKWebViewConfiguration.setURLSchemeHandler` with http/https schemes because of the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: ''https' is a URL scheme that WKWebView handles natively'
```

This happens because `WKWebView.handlesURLScheme` is called inside and generates this error in case of returned `true`. Thus we can use an approach by swizzling this method and it allows to handle http/https schemes as well as custom ones.

```swift
func swizzleClassMethod(cls: AnyClass, origSelector: Selector, newSelector: Selector) {
  guard let origMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, origSelector),
        let newMethod = class_getClassMethod(cls, newSelector),
        let cls = object_getClass(cls)
  else {
    return
  }
  
  if class_addMethod(cls, origSelector, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod)) {
    class_replaceMethod(cls, newSelector, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod))
  }
  else {
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, newMethod)
  }
}

extension WKWebView {
  @objc
  static func _handlesURLScheme(_ urlScheme: String) -> Bool {
    false // Allow all schemes
  }
}

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  swizzleClassMethod(cls: WKWebView.self,
                     origSelector: #selector(WKWebView.handlesURLScheme),
                     newSelector: #selector(WKWebView._handlesURLScheme))

  return true
}
```

Now we can set http/https schemes and intercept all `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` inside `WKWebView`, for instance:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let js = """
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
  .then(response => {
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(text => {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<br> fetch:" + text;
  })

  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 3) {
      document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<br> ajax:" + this.responseText;
    }
  };
  ajax.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users", true);
  ajax.send();
  """
  let script = WKUserScript(source: js, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
  let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
  config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

  config.setURLSchemeHandler(self, forURLScheme: "https")

  webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: config)
  view.addSubview(webView)
  webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body id='body'></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
}
```

```swift
extension ViewController: WKURLSchemeHandler {
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
    let json = #"[{"login": "mojombo","id": 1}, {"login": "defunkt", "id": 2}]"#
    
    let response = HTTPURLResponse(
      url: urlSchemeTask.request.url!,
      statusCode: 200,
      httpVersion: nil,
      headerFields: [ "access-control-allow-origin": "*"]
    )!
    
    urlSchemeTask.didReceive(response)
    urlSchemeTask.didReceive(json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    urlSchemeTask.didFinish()
  }
  
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
fetch:[{"login": "mojombo","id": 1}, {"login": "defunkt", "id": 2}]
ajax:[{"login": "mojombo","id": 1}, {"login": "defunkt", "id": 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the requests from a `WKWebView` using the `WKNavigationDelegate`.
You may override `webView:decidePolicyFor:...` to inspect the request, check for its type (e.g. link clicked, form submitted, etc.) and inspect the associated `URL` to take some action:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }

    // WKNavigationDelegate method to intercept resource requests
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        // `navigationType` indicates how this request got created
        // `.other` may indicate an Ajax request
        // More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationtype

        // Update: remove the if clause for now and see if you get any result for your Ajax requests.
        // if navigationAction.navigationType == .other {
            if let request = navigationAction.request.url {
                print("Resource Request: \(request)")
            }
        // }

        // Allow the navigation to continue or not, depending on your business logic
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't see any Ajax requests showing up here

Comment: I have tried with this website: 
"https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html"
The delegate method fires, although this check `navigationAction.navigationType == .other` doesn't do it. Can you remove this if statement and try again?

Comment: Unfortunately even by removing that check, it doesn't work. It look like that delegate is not able to intercept all resource requests.